# Javascript Date Format with "month day, year hour:minute:second am/pm"

Tags: javascript

How to get this date format? 
    `Apr 22, 2018 12:44:58 PM`

I've tried this code `(new Date()).toUTCString()` but the result is like 
           `Sun, 22 Apr 2018 10:45:19 GMT`

Comment: [Check out the answers on this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is to leverage [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com) - you can then use:

```
moment().format('MMM DD, YYYY hh:mm:ss A')
```

Comment: This should be a comment. The OP has not tagged or mentioned any libraries.